# What happens to existing FBML Code once Mark Zuckerberg removes FBML?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, fbjs

I have just added the fb:comments FBML tag to a site.

Working 100%, but Facebook has a notification on the top of the documentation that reads:

"***FBML has been deprecated.*** Starting June 1, 2012 FBML apps will no longer work as all FBML endpoints will be removed." - Ref : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_%28XFBML%29/

What happens to all existing Websites and Apps that uses FBML? Will it just be disabled?

I have to switch to **FBJS** , I am not sure that all FBML features are available in FBJS...

**Example:**

I am using the following code to add the facebook comments to my website:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{URL}" data-num-posts="30" data-width="626" publish_feed="true"></div>
```

I have worked with FBJS before, coding a successful oAuth Login, getting the logged in status, posting to wall etc.

**How would I create fb:comments in FBJS?**

OR

**Will FBML still work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood a couple of things here:

1. FBJS **is** [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/) too, I guess you mean [Javascript-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
2. XFBML **will** continue to work, refer to this [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/568/).
3. **Always** refer to the [roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/).
4. I'm not really sure if Mark **himself** will remove the FBML support.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! Great post with links!

Answer (score 1):

From the Facebook API site concerning the use of XFBML in FBJS:

> *The JavaScript SDK lets you use the XFBML implementations of Social Plugins.*

Social Plugins, according to their page, include the 'comments plugin', which contains XFBML, that also, when used in the FB API, maintains a structure of

```
<fb:comments>
```

I don't know what they're deprecating in the 'FBML", but "XFBML" seems to be going strong.